# writing a boolean decision variable in cplex

Tags: variables, parameters, set, boolean, cplex

PLEASE HELP ME:  i have a boolean decision variable. moreover, set t itself in the domain of this variable should be calculated from an equation.**

Xro^t={1     if request  r∈R_τ   is assigned to offer o ∈ O_τ   at time period t∈ Γ_ro,
0      Otherwise}
Γ_ro= [p, a]∩z

in this case, i am not sure if Γ_ro is a set or is a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on tuple set in order not to do the full Euclidian product:

```
range R=1..4;
range O=1..3;

int Tstart[r in R][o in O]=rand(5);
int Tend[r in R][o in O]=Tstart[r][o]+rand(4);

tuple rot
{
  int r;
  int o;
  int t;
}

sorted {rot} rots={<r,o,t> | r in R,o in O,t  in Tstart[r][o]..Tend[r][o]};

dvar boolean x[rots];

minimize sum(i in rots) x[i];
subject to
{
  
}
```